# flex - flip down digits display, like retro clock?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3

I want to display a number in my app so that the digits are styled like a retro-style clock, where each digit looks like a flippable tag (e.g., http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/learn-how-to-create-a-retro-animated-flip-down-clock/).  I don't actually require any animation or effects.

Does such a component exist in an open source library?  If not, and I want to make my own component, what suggestions do you have for proceeding (e.g., should I just style a label or button, or ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into this before too.  I couldn't find any open source versions, but I did find a few available on activeden.net that were relatively inexpensive.  None of them suited my needs though.  If I were to create one myself for Flex 3, I would create a custom component that had hours and minutes for properties, then override the updateDisplayList method to draw my flip numbers.  Alternatively you could have your custom component display a couple of images and update their source properties to point to the appropriate embedded flip number image.  If Flex 4 is an option for you, you could do all of this in a custom skin for your component.  Hope that helps.